# Embedded tomcat slow process the requests - Spring Boot

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, thymeleaf, embedded-tomcat-8

I'm using Spring boot 1.5.8 with Embedded tomcat and Thymeleaf for the view.
The problem is that from time to time when some request is sent, the tomcat is blocked and process the request too long time ~10 -~15 sec. From the log file, i saw that this delay comes from org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.

```
2017-12-07 08:36:34.005 TRACE 15354 --- [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-8] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Publishing event in org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1c6b6478: ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/tiles/add]; client=[IP]; method=[GET]; servlet=[dispatcherServlet]; session=[32AC651D46CA6EC730F651BBC9F9B573]; user=[admin]; time=[9ms]; status=[OK]
2017-12-07 08:36:34.005 DEBUG 15354 --- [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-8] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@7de5a5db
2017-12-07 08:36:34.682 DEBUG 15354 --- [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-13] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@7de5a5db
2017-12-07 08:36:43.796 TRACE 15354 --- [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-13] o.t.TemplateEngine                       : [THYMELEAF][https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-13] STARTING PROCESS OF TEMPLATE "tile/add" WITH LOCALE en_US
```

As you can see, the first line is when the first request is finished, and when the new request is bound to the thread in the third line. The time between third and fourth row is ~10 seconds. When thymeleaf starts to process the view.

Comment: Did it occurred for the first request after starting the tomcat server or every request ?

Comment: The problem is that this happens on a random time principle. I notice that more often it occurs with POST request.

Comment: Did you check the Available Memory or Disk IO rate?

Comment: This occurs in non highly loaded site and the Disk IO shouldn't be the problem. There is enough memory in the heap.

Comment: If you have set up a benchmark for this, I would test different tomcat versions for this (you can change Spring Boot's embedded tomcat version without the need to change the entire Boot version). I would try: Using tomcat 7, using an earlier tomcat 8 version and with the last available tomcat 8 version.

Comment: I will try with tomcat 7. Before to update to 1.5.8 and tomcat 8.x, i used spring boot 1.4.x with tomcat  version below the current one .. and the problem was existing too