# Spring boot 2 Embedded tomcat 8 - slow request handling

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat8

After some questions about this topic -

[Spring boot - slow method execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48260078/spring-boot-slow-method-execution)

[Embedded tomcat slow process the requests - Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47689278/embedded-tomcat-slow-process-the-requests-spring-boot)

I finally installed perfino to monitor the production server. I catched the method execution that cause the problem (I'm not sure on 100% but..)
As you can see from the attached image, the problem comes from

```
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass (line: 121)
```

which takes 9ms to complete.

As my observations this occurs only with POST request.

Any suggestions from where this problem comes ?

[image]

Most of the time this request takes no more than 60ms
[image]

Comment: Thanks.. I don't have the problem after I updated to spring boot 2.2, but you comments very helpful. Thanks!